# Как написать ассемблерную вставку на С под gcc?

Tags: c, ассемблер

Как написать ассемблерную вставку на С. Компилирую в gcc:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
   int a = 1, b = 2, c = 0;

   __asm {
      mov eax, a;
      mov ebx, b;
      add eax, ebx;
      mov c, eax;
   }

   printf("%x + %x = %x\n", a, b, c);

   return 0;
}
```

В Visual C++ 6.0 все норм. А вот в gcc в cygwin нет. В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 3):

У GCC другой формат встроенного ассемблера. Вот [документация](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html). И [вот ещё](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html) (вроде более читабельно).

Кроме того, там другие соглашения об использовании регистров. Кроме того, в AT&T-шном синтаксисе порядок источника и приёмника строго противоположный привычному в интеловском мире.

Вообще, ассемблерные вставки — самая непортабельная часть языка (в стандарте их вовсе нет).

Comment: Я не силен в английском. Может подскажите на примере как это сделать в gcc?

Comment: @dr_kraken, гугл предлагает:


[вот материал на русском](http://asmcourse.cs.msu.ru/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/gcc-inline-asm.pdf), 

[вот еще](http://www.opennet.ru/base/dev/from_c_to_asm.txt.html),

[подробно на английском](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html) 

и [кратко на русском](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GCC_Inline_Assembly)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Помогло.